# Query a transformed field with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to filter the results of a query using a transformed field as parameter. My goal is to get all users that are visiting a city at the moment, so I calculate dateTo - dateFrom using a transform method, and if it's greater than 0, then I display the user.

Here is the code

```
Exchanges = new Mongo.Collection('exchanges', {
  transform: (doc) => {
    const dateFromDiff = moment(doc.dateFromISO).diff(moment());
    const dateToDiff = moment(doc.dateToISO).diff(moment());

    doc.time = dateToDiff >= 0 && dateFromDiff <= 0 ? 'present' : (dateToDiff < 0 && dateFromDiff < 0 ? 'past' : 'future');
    return doc;
  },
});
```

However, when I'm using the new time field to get the users

```
Exchanges.find({ city: 'Budapest', time: 'present' });
```

I get an empty array. I expected to get a performant, reactive and filtered array. That's why I'm using mongoDB with Meteor. Any idea?

Comment: Does it work using native mongo query with `$gt` ? Also, does it work with native `Date` objects?

Comment: It works! thank you Jankapunkt

Comment: Which one of my suggestions work? (Just important for others who search the same issue and may find this post, too)

Comment: good idea. I'm using Exchanges.find({ city, dateFromISO: { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }, dateToISO: { $gte: (new Date().toISOString()) } })